# counting the unchecked checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql

```
$chk = $_POST['chk'];
$count = count($chk);
for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
$abc = $chk[$i];

$query = mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_softwareinstalled SET status = 'Enabled' WHERE vendor = '$abc'");

}
```

I have a code here that counts the checked checkboxes and updates 'tbl_softwareinstalled' that has a column of 'status' with 'enabled'. My problem is how can I count the unchecked checkboxes on my table, setting the `status = 'Disabled'`? Thanks a lot folks.

Comment: I really hope you're escaping `$abc` in your actual application.

Comment: What do you mean escaping? Sorry

Comment: It's a SQL injection hole. Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: If you don't know what escaping is, you should stop whatever you're doing and read up on it *right now*. You're one malicious user away from having your entire database utterly trashed. You can't be too diligent with this sort of thing, even in applications used by "trusted" users. As soon as "Jimmy O'Malley" signs up for your application it will crash. As a bonus, [this joke](http://xkcd.com/327/) will also make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You will only get parameters for those checkboxes that have been checked. You will need to add `hidden` values to supply defaults. For example:

```
<input name="check_1" type="hidden" value="0">
<input name="check_1" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

If the checkbox is checked, `check_1` will be `'1'`, otherwise it will be `'0'`.

Comment: Then how will I count the unchecked ones?

Comment: They will come through with a value of `'0'` instead of `'1'`, so respond accordingly.